# Mariadb points to old version after upgrade

Tags: mysql, windows, upgrade, mariadb

I just upgraded my MariaDB from 10.1 to 10.2. Nevertheless, when I run `mysql -V` command, it still points to version 10.1.

I have two folders in `Program Files` folder: MariaDB 10.2 and MariaDB 10.1.

How do I change it? It's crucial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PATH environment variable to point to the new directory.

Comment: What if I'm using PowerShell?)

Comment: Okay. Figured it out, changing it in advanced system variables will suffice

Comment: It must have been set somewehere to be looking at the old versio. Reset it whereever that is

Comment: yeah, surprisingly Windows has a PATH variable, too ;)